# Manually Sync Outlook 2010 contacts/calendar only from Windows PC to Android cell phone (Samsung Galaxy S II) via USB cord only

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2, calendar

How do I manually Sync Outlook 2010 contacts and calendar only from Windows PC to Android cell phone (Samsung Galaxy S II) via USB cord only. I do NOT want to use any kind of web based product, i.e. Google, nor pay 3rd party software program to do this, unless I have to. I don’t want automatic syncing; I just want control of my data by plugging my cell into my computer via USB cord and manually hitting sync.  If I make a change to contacts or calendar on my cell, when I plug it into my computer it transfers data and vice versa without it cutting off data in the notes of contacts or anywhere else because web based products only allow a certain amount of data to transfer. Also, what applications do I need to have on my cell phone for the contacts and calendar to work? I use Gmail separately for my emails by going to Google, but do not want that on Outlook 2010. Also, NO I will not give up Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use third party software then you need to use Samsung's Kies.  It says [here](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/mobilesoftwaremanual/mobilesoftwaremanual.do?page=MOBILE.SOFTWARE.MANUAL) that it supports syncing with Outlook, though I don't know the details.